# Values for uilabels of custom tableview cell is not being set

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

Im using a tableview with custom cells.

Following is my cellForRowAtIndexPath method.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

//    AssigneeCell *cell = (AssigneeCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell"];

    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    AssigneeCell * cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

    if (!cell)
    {
        [tableView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"AssigneewiseView" bundle:nil] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"Cell"];
        cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell"];

        NSLog(@"call");
    }

    cell.unitNameVal = unitNameResult[indexPath.row];
    cell.domainNameVal = domainNameResult[indexPath.row];
    cell.compliedVal = compliedResult[indexPath.row];
    cell.delayedVal = delayedResult[indexPath.row];
    cell.inProgressVal = inProgressResult[indexPath.row];
    cell.notCompliedVal = notCompliedResult[indexPath.row];
    cell.totalVal = totalValResult[indexPath.row];

    return cell;
}


- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{

    return [compliedResult count];
}
```

numberOfRowsInSection is called and hence my tableview contains  multiple views depending upon the count of compliedResult.

But the problem is that, the values for uilabels present in my custom cell is not being assigned and hence its not visible. Why is that so?

Comment: try to print compiledResult.count in numberOfRowsInSection and make sure it is not 0

Comment: Are you using storyboard for tableview and cell or xib for cell ?

Comment: yes...Im using storyboard for tableview and xib for cell

Comment: Is cells are visible, are you able to scroll?

Comment: Yes Im able to scroll and the cells are visible too.

Comment: Is there anywhere something like "cell.label.text = ..."?

Comment: If `unitNameVal`, `domainNameVal`, etc.. are labels, should you be setting the `text` property of them?

Comment: what is unitNameResult, domainNameResult, array? what is it holding?

Comment: @ Luca ... unitNameVal,domainNameVal etc...are the names of label in my custom tableview cell

Comment: @ j.f You mean creating IBOutlets? yes I have done it as well

Comment: did you try to set the text property of your labels ?@KaruppuMGR

Comment: you have to do cell.unitNameVal.text= instead of cell.unitNameVal= @KaruppuMGR

Comment: In this case @j.f. answer is ok, for instance: cell.unitNameVal.text = unitNameResult[indexPath.row];

Comment: @ feroz yes unitNameResult, domainNameResult are NSMutableArrays

Comment: I have created the property already....

Comment: He is referring to cell.label.text In your case you should give cell.unitNameVal.text = unitNameResult[indexPath.row];

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First suggestion, create your model:

```
@interface Result: NSObject
@property (nonatomic) NSString* unitName;
@property (nonatomic) NSString* domainName;
@property (nonatomic) NSString* complied;
@property (nonatomic) NSString* delayed;
@property (nonatomic) NSString* inProgress;
@property (nonatomic) NSString* notComplied;
@property (nonatomic) NSString* totalVal;
@end
```

In this way, your viewController will have an array of Result object.

Inside your custom cell, define:

```
@implementation AssigneeCell

+ (NSString*)cellIdentifier {
   return @"Cell";
}

- (void)setupWithResult:(Result*)result {
    self.unitNameVal.text = result.unitName;
    self.domainNameVal.text = result.domainName;
    self.compliedVal.text = result.complied;
    self.delayedVal.text = result.delayed;
    self.inProgressVal.text = result.inProgress;
    self.notCompliedVal.text = result.notComplied;
    self.totalVal.text = result.totalVal;
} 

@end
```

Finally in your view controller:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {  
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];  
    [self.tableView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"AssigneewiseView" bundle:nil] forCellReuseIdentifier:[AssigneeCell cellIdentifier]];
}

- (UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView*)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath {
    static NSString* cellIdentifier = [AssigneeCell cellIdentifier];
    AssigneeCell* cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    [cell setupWithResult: results[indexPath.row]]; 
    return cell;
}
```

This ensure **clean code** and **code reuse**.

Comment: Good suggestion. Much cleaner.

Comment: what is results in  results[indexPath.row]]

Comment: You have to define, in your view controller, an array of Result.

Answer (score 1):

Since `unitNameVal`, `domainNameVal`, etc. are labels, make sure you are setting their text property. What you are doing right now is setting the labels themselves as different objects.

Assuming your arrays are arrays of strings, this should do the trick for you:

```
cell.unitNameVal.text = unitNameResult[indexPath.row];
cell.domainNameVal.text = domainNameResult[indexPath.row];
...
```